# exporting the data gives error when the type is 'smalldatetime' and value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL server, I have a table with 'smalldatetime' data type for one of the column. When I am trying to export the data using Microsoft SQL server import/export wizard, it is giving me conversion error because the field contains NULL value in Date field. Can you please help me in resolving this error.
What steps need to be followed in order to resolve the conversion error.

Comment: Where do you try to export to?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, i am trying to export it to Excel .

Comment: I just tried the same myself in SQL Server 2016 Standard and it works without an issue. What version do you have? And which provider do you use?

Comment: Check mapping (`Edit mappings...` button) to find any strange relations and try to create new destination file. Using the export wizard is not a sophisticated thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to copy "table to table" or "query to table"?
Cause if your problem is only with null values you can write a query and use ISNULL() function.

Can you post the error here?  I´m asking cause maybe your problem isn´t it. Maybe you´re trying to convert a type into another that is not compatible.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2016

Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".
 
Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with Destination - Measurements.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[PIPELINERUNDATE] on Destination - Measurements.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type."